# system won't power-down on shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, ubuntu-gnome

This desktop amd64 running 18.04 has been running fine for about 5 months. A few days ago, a strange problem started.

On shutdown, Ubuntu shutdown appears to be normal, then the video is cut.
However, system power remains on until I do a hardware reset or by the power switch.

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1773291 , but no solution yet.

Comment: @N0rbert Could be, but system had been ok and no software updates 2 days prior to the first occurrence. That day, the desktop froze while opening multiple files in vlc player, so my guess would be along the lines of some file corruption.

Comment: Do a full disk check and then try again.  Try from the terminal "sudo shutdown now".  See if that works.  As a temporary workaround you  can shutdown that way.

Comment: @walttheboss  I tried "sudo shutdown now" and still no power off (same as commented in the linked question), but in the log there wasn't any "fail whale" error, nor any other error I could identify. So I guess I'll have to edit this question. As for "fsck", what is the best way to run it on the boot volume? Recovery mode won't because the volume is mounted. Can I run it from the live CD? I did confirm shutdown was OK from the live CD.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  This has happened to me with older desktops.  Something fails in the M-Board or Power Supply and it can't shutdown.  I have never copmletely solved it.  We shut down and then force down with the power button.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, this is a bug issue with kernal 5.3.0.53 (seems 52+ are affected) in amd64 processor (Ryzen) systems with integrated graphics.

For detailed information, see [Failing to shutdown/power off or reboot on AMD Ryzen CPUs on kernel versions 5.3.0-52 and later](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041)

Looks like it will be fixed in the next kernal release. For now I am using 5.3.0.51 which works correctly.

--UPDATE--

This has been fixed as of 5.3.0-59